# QRS detection(peaks) of a raw ecg signal in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I want to find the peaks of the raw ecg signal so that I can calculate the beats per minute(bpm).
I Have written a code in matlab which I have attached below.In the code below I am unable to find threshold point correctly which will help me in finding the peaks and hence the bpm.

```
%input the signal into matlab

[x,fs]=wavread('heartbeat.wav');
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(x(1:10000),'r-')
grid on



%lowpass filter the input signal with cutoff at 100hz
h=fir1(30,0.3126);     %normalized cutoff freq=0.3126
y=filter(h,1,x);

subplot(2,1,2)
plot(y(1:10000),'b-')
grid on



% peaks are seen as pulses(heart beats)
beat_count=0;
for p=2:length(y)-1
    th(p)=abs(max(y(p)));
    if(y(p) >y(p-1) && y(p) >y(p+1) && y(p)>th(p))
        beat_count=beat_count+1;
    end
end

N = length(y);
duration_seconds=N/fs;
duration_minutes=duration_seconds/60;
BPM=beat_count/duration_minutes;
bpm=ceil(BPM);
```

Please help me as I am new to matlab

Comment: Hi, I suggest that you explain the logic behind your peak detection algorithm rather than expecting people to understand it just from the code. Also `abs(max(y(p)))` doesn't make a lot of sense as `y(p)` is a scalar so `max(y(p))` is just `y(p)`, perhaps you meant `max(y)`?

Comment: @Dan yup...i meant by max(y)....By finding the threshold ,I can compare a value of y with its previous value,its next value and the threshold value.if the value is greater than all the 3 conditions then it is considered as a peak point.

Comment: 100 Hz is a crazy high cutoff for filtering QRSs from ECG data. You probably want more like about 15-30 Hz. You also want a high-pass filter with a cut-off of about 5 Hz to get rid of baseline drift etc. Further to that, you should probably be using `filtfilt` so there is no phase distortion - after all, in this case you ARE interested in what the time history looks like. You might also consider using [the Pan & Tompkins algorithm](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~gari/teaching/cdt/A3/readings/ECG/Pan+Tompkins.pdf), which works very well.

Comment: i am also applying same thing in ios i hope you got the solution but there are two ways either you find the slope or you get the distance from the old coordinates to the new , i am also glad if i get help in ios

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest changing this section of your code

```
beat_count=0;
for p=2:length(y)-1
    th(p)=abs(max(y(p)));
    if(y(p) >y(p-1) && y(p) >y(p+1) && y(p)>th(p))
        beat_count=beat_count+1;
    end
end
```

This is definitely flawed. I'm not sure of your logic here but what about this. We are looking for peaks, but only the high peaks, so first lets set a threshold value (you'll have to tweak this to a sensible number) and cull everything below that value to get rid of the smaller peaks:

```
th = max(y) * 0.9; %So here I'm considering anything less than 90% of the max as not a real peak... this bit really depends on your logic of finding peaks though which you haven't explained
Yth = zeros(length(y), 1);
Yth(y > th) = y(y > th);
```

OK so I suggest you now plot y and Yth to see what that code did. Now to find the peaks my logic is we are looking for local maxima i.e. points at which the first derivative of the function change from being positive to being negative. So I'm going to find a very simple numerical approximation to the first derivative by finding the difference between each consecutive point on the signal:

```
Ydiff = diff(Yth);
```

No I want to find where the signal goes from being positive to being negative. So I'm going to make all the positive values equal zero, and all the negative values equal one:

```
Ydiff_logical = Ydiff < 0;
```

finally I want to find where this signal changes from a zero to a one (but not the other way around)

```
Ypeaks = diff(Ydiff_logical) == 1;
```

Now count the peaks:

```
sum(Ypeaks)
```

note that for plotting purpouse because of the use of diff we should pad a false to either side of Ypeaks so

```
Ypeaks = [false; Ypeaks; false];
```

OK so there is quite a lot of matlab there, I suggest you run each line, one by one and inspect the variable by both plotting the result of each line and also by double clicking the variable in the matlab workspace to understand what is happening at each step.

**Example:** (signal `PeakSig` taken from http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) and plotting with:

```
plot(x(Ypeaks),PeakSig(Ypeaks),'k^','markerfacecolor',[1 0 0]);
```

[image]

Comment: Yth = zeros(length(y), 1);
Yth(y > th) = y(y > th); I didn't understand why you are assigning zeros to Yth and I would like to know which matlab version  you are using as PeakSig is not found in mine!

Comment: Yes `PeakSig` is, as I said in the answer, just a signal that I grabbed from the docs. It's not built into matlab it's from the link I provided! It's just an example, you must use your ECG signal, I had to make up a signal as you did not provide one.

Comment: The reason I am assigning zeros is so that everything below the threshold is set to zero to eliminate the smaller peaks, that's why only the top three peaks (or more precisely the peaks that are at least 90% of the absolute max) are detected.

Comment: I used the method suggested by you in the above post..but could not get the actual result i.e detecting the actual R peaks.Attached the link of the pic..please guide me how it can be detected for such figures..http://www.hostpic.org/view.php?filename=1304251341240092.jpg

Comment: Wow that's a seriously noisy signal. Is it just me or is your filtered signal identical to your unfiltered signal. I suggest you post a new question with some example data and the code implementing this method so we can see where you've gone wrong. And did you try `findpeaks` like @fpe suggested?

Comment: tried findpeaks algorithm but in vain...the unfiltered signal looks similar to filtered signal when all the samples(48000 samples) are plotted..but when only certain set of samples are plotted the difference can be known...

Comment: Repost the question, with your new code and a subset of the samples

Comment: re posted the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210280/finding-r-peak-from-a-heart-signal-input-from-a-stethoscope

Answer (score 2):

What do you think about the built-in

```
findpeaks(data,'Name',value)
```

function? You can choose among different logics for peak detection:

```
'MINPEAKHEIGHT'
'MINPEAKDISTANCE'
'THRESHOLD'
'NPEAKS'
'SORTSTR'
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note this is part of the signal processing toolbox. But pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

You know, the QRS complex does not always have the maximum amplitude, for pathologic ECG it can be present as several minor oscillations instead of one high-amplitude peak.

Thus, you can try one good algothythm, tested by me: the detection criterion is assumed to be high absolute rate of change in the signal, averaged within the given interval.

Algorithm:
- 50/60 Hz filter (e.g. for 50 Hz sliding window of 20 msec will be fine)
- adaptive hipass filter (for baseline drift)
- find signal's first derivate x'
- fing squared derivate (x')^2
- apply sliding average window with the width of QRS complex - approx 100-150 msec (you will get some signal with 'rectangles', which have width of QRS)
- use simple threshold (e.g. 1/3 of maximum of the first 3 seconds) to determine approximate positions or R
- in the source ECG find local maximum within +-100 msec of that R position.

However, you still have to eliminate artifacts and outliers (e.g. surges, when the electrod connection fails).

Also, you can find a lot of helpful information from this book: "R.M. Rangayyan - Biomedical Signal Analysis"