# Finding R peak from a heart signal input from a stethoscope

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

Given an heart beat signal measured using a stethoscope  to the audio card of the computer through a hardware(mainly amplifier and low pass filter having cutoff frequency 100hz).
Now the signal is filtered with cutoff 100hz..the code to find the peak and beats per minute is given below..The code works only for certain cases.
Please help me find the mistake

```
clear all
%input the signal into matlab


[x,fs]=wavread('heartbeat.wav');
figure(1)
subplot(2,1,1)
x1=x(:,2);
plot(x1(500:10000),'r-');
title('unfiltered input x(n),cut off frequency 0.0270,passband 60hz,stopband 70hz');
ylabel('amplitude in volts');
xlabel('number of samples')
grid on

%to filter the signal above 50-60 hz
order=4;
h=fir1(4,0.0270,hamming(order+1));
y=filter(h,1,x1);
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(y(500:10000),'b-')
title('filtered output y(n),cut off frequency 0.0270,passband 50hz,stopband 60hz');
ylabel('amplitude in volts');
xlabel('number of samples')
grid on
%sound(y,5000)


th = max(y) * 0.9; %So here I'm considering anything less than 90% of the max as not a real peak... this bit really depends on your logic of finding peaks though which you haven't explained
Yth = zeros(length(y), 1);
Yth(y > th) = y(y > th);

Ydiff = diff(Yth);
Ydiff_logical = Ydiff < 0;
Ypeaks = diff(Ydiff_logical) == 1;

p=sum(Ypeaks)

N = length(y);
duration_seconds=N/fs;
duration_minutes=duration_seconds/60;
BPM=p/duration_minutes;
bpm=ceil(BPM)




figure(2)
%frequency response of the filter
freqz(h,1)
title('Frequency response');
xlabel('normalized frequency (X pi) radians per sample');
ylabel('Magnitude');
grid on;
```

Comment: How does this in any way implement the code I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167433/qrs-detectionpeaks-of-a-raw-ecg-signal-in-matlab/16168120?noredirect=1#comment23180788_16168120 ? Also some example data showing for what cases the code doesn't work is essential

Comment: @Dan sorry about that .... th = max(y) * 0.9; works only for one signal while for rest i have to change 90% to 60%(gambling)...given a screenshot where the beats per minute is 1(which cannot be!)..http://www.hostpic.org/view.php?filename=1304251428350096.jpg  and the threshold value is 0.2647 which is very high to detect the peaks..

Comment: Post. Example. Data. 

Or else ask on dsp.stackexchange.com if your question is how to threshhold properly.

Comment: It might help if you posted an image of a small section of your data. This is a different problem to your previous question because that was about ECG and this is a totally different type of signal. I can't speak for anyone else here but I'm certainly not familiar with stethoscope audio recordings. As such, it's hard to tell if your filtering is appropriate. You should also plot the locations at which you detect a heartbeat to check that the thresholding is working, not just look at the output BPM.

Answer (score 0):

Without example data I'm just guessing, but I don't think thresholding is going to get you the right data: in all likelihood, the peaks are different height each time (by "each time" I mean both each run and each individual beat). Therefore, if you use too high a peak, it will miss some real peaks because the heartbeat will be too low. If you use too low a peak, you risk double-counting some heartbeats beacuase each heartbeat contains multiple peaks (Sorry I don't remember what these are called). It's likely that things will change over time, as well, so I wouldn't even try to set the threshold for an individual recording and let it go, or even deriving threshold from the data could be problematic.

You will likely have better luck with other techniques such as cross-correlation or some sort of modified zero-crossing, or something specifically designed for the unique features of heartbeats (I imagine there is something. Have you searched the literature?).

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment on the OP's previous question, a popular (although probably a bit dusty nowadays - there might be newer incarnations) algorithm is the [Pan & Tompkins](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~gari/teaching/cdt/A3/readings/ECG/Pan+Tompkins.pdf) algorithm for ECG QRS detection, which actually uses a pair of thresholds and some simple adaptive threshold update rules based on the usual timings of heartbeats.